# Why does LC_SYMTAB have invalid stroff/strsize but only for some loaded images?

Tags: c, macos, dyld, mach-o

I wrote the below program to iterate over all images in memory and dump their string tables.

```
#include <mach-o/dyld.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    uint32_t count = _dyld_image_count();
    for (uint32_t i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {
        const char* imageName = _dyld_get_image_name(i);
        printf("IMAGE[%u]=%s\n", i, imageName);
        const struct mach_header* header = _dyld_get_image_header(i);
        if (header->magic != MH_MAGIC_64)
            continue;
        struct mach_header_64* header64 = (struct mach_header_64*)header;
        char *ptr = ((void*)header64) + sizeof(struct mach_header_64);
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < header64->ncmds; j++) {
            struct load_command *lc = (struct load_command *)ptr;
            ptr += lc->cmdsize;
            if (lc->cmd != LC_SYMTAB)
                continue;
            struct symtab_command* symtab = (struct symtab_command*)lc;
            printf("\t\tLC_SYMTAB.stroff=%u\n", symtab->stroff);
            printf("\t\tLC_SYMTAB.strsize=%u\n", symtab->strsize);
            if (symtab->strsize > 100*1024*1024) {
                printf("\t\tHUH? Don't believe string table is over 100MiB in size!\n");
                continue;
            }
            char *strtab = (((void*)header64) + symtab->stroff);
            uint32_t off = 0;
            while (off < symtab->strsize) {
                char *e = &(strtab[off]);
                if (e[0] != 0)
                    printf("\t\tSTR[%u]=\"%s\"\n", off, e);
                off += strlen(e) + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It seems to randomly work for some images, but for others the stroff/strsize have nonsensical values:

```
        LC_SYMTAB.stroff=1266154560
        LC_SYMTAB.strsize=143767728
```

It seems to always be the same two magic values, but I'm not sure if this is system-dependent in some way or if other people will get the same specific values.

If I comment out the check for strsize being over 100MiB, then printing the string table segfaults.

Most images seem to have this problem, but some don't. When I run it, I get the issue for 29 images out of 38.

I can't observe any pattern as to which do and which won't. What is going on here?

If it is relevant, I am testing on macOS 10.14.6 and compiling with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4).

Comment: I kind of worked out what is going on here: the images with this problem are in the dyld shared cache, and you can tell that because the undocumented `0x80000000` bit on the `flags` of the `mach_header_64` is set. That suggests `stroff`/`strsize` are relative to the dyld shared cache. I tried using the return value of the undocumented `_dyld_get_shared_cache_range` API as base address to add `stroff` to, but that still doesn't give me a valid string table.

Comment: I think I actually need to do what the lldb source code is doing [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/ffb3fd8f1846de97d10cfca249567eb282cec980/lldb/source/Plugins/ObjectFile/Mach-O/ObjectFileMachO.cpp#L2373), although I'm still trying to understand what that code is doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already worked out, those are from the `dyld_shared_cache`. And the `0x80000000` flag is indeed documented, in the headers shipped with Xcode or [any semi-recent XNU source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-6153.141.1/EXTERNAL_HEADERS/mach-o/loader.h.auto.html):

```
#define MH_DYLIB_IN_CACHE 0x80000000    /* Only for use on dylibs. When this bit
                                           is set, the dylib is part of the dyld
                                           shared cache, rather than loose in
                                           the filesystem. */
```

As you've also discovered, the `stroff`/`strsize` values do not yield usable results when added to the `dyld_shared_cache` base. That is because those are not *memory* offsets, but *file* offsets. This is true for all Mach-O's, it's just often the case that the segments of non-cached binaries have the same relative position in file and memory offsets. But this is definitely not true for the shared cache.

To translate the file offset into a memory address, you'll have to parse the segments in the shared cache header. You can find struct definitions [in the dyld source](https://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-750.6/launch-cache/dyld_cache_format.h.auto.html).

Comment: Thanks. That was basically it. Once I found the appropriate mapping, I then had to do `(void*)(mappings[i].address - mappings[0].address + (offset - mappings[i].fileOffset) + (uint64_t)sharedCacheBaseAddress)`

Comment: I got it working, and posted my working code as my own answer. I accepted yours because you gave me the key to getting it working.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a program which prints out the contents of the string table of the `dyld` shared cache.

My original program in the question can be enhanced to skip dumping string table of images with `MH_DYLIB_IN_CACHE` set, and combined with this program to dump the shared cache string table. (All images in the shared cache share the same string table.)

```
#include <mach-o/dyld.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

const void* _dyld_get_shared_cache_range(size_t* cacheLen);

struct dyld_cache_header {
        char            magic[16];
        uint32_t        mappingOffset;
        uint32_t        mappingCount;
        // Omitted remaining fields, not relevant to this task
};

struct dyld_cache_mapping_info {
    uint64_t    address;
    uint64_t    size;
    uint64_t    fileOffset;
    uint32_t    maxProt;
    uint32_t    initProt;
};

#ifndef MH_DYLIB_IN_CACHE
#       define MH_DYLIB_IN_CACHE 0x80000000
#endif

// Finds first shared cache DYLD image. Any will do, just grab the first
const struct mach_header_64* findSharedCacheDyldImage(void) {
        uint32_t count = _dyld_image_count();
        for (uint32_t i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) {
                const struct mach_header* header = _dyld_get_image_header(i);
                if (header->magic != MH_MAGIC_64)
                        continue;
                const struct mach_header_64* header64 = (const struct mach_header_64*)header;
                if (!(header64->flags & MH_DYLIB_IN_CACHE))
                        continue;
                return header64;
        }
        return NULL;
}

// Find first instance of given load command in image
const struct load_command* findFirstLoadCommand(const struct mach_header_64* header64, uint32_t cmd) {
        const char *ptr = ((void*)header64) + sizeof(struct mach_header_64);
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < header64->ncmds; j++) {
                const struct load_command *lc = (const struct load_command *)ptr;
                ptr += lc->cmdsize;
                if (lc->cmd == cmd)
                        return lc;
        }
        return NULL;
}

// Translates a shared cache file offset to a memory address
void *translateOffset(const struct dyld_cache_header *cache, uint64_t offset) {
        const struct dyld_cache_mapping_info* mappings = (struct dyld_cache_mapping_info*)(((void*)cache) + cache->mappingOffset);
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < cache->mappingCount; i++) {
                if (offset < mappings[i].fileOffset) continue;
                if (offset >= (mappings[i].fileOffset + mappings[i].size)) continue;
                return (void*)(mappings[i].address - mappings[0].address + (offset - mappings[i].fileOffset) + (uint64_t)cache);
        }
        return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        size_t cacheLen;
        const struct dyld_cache_header *cache = _dyld_get_shared_cache_range(&cacheLen);
        const struct mach_header_64* sharedCacheDyldImage = findSharedCacheDyldImage();
        const struct symtab_command* symtab = (const struct symtab_command*)findFirstLoadCommand(sharedCacheDyldImage,LC_SYMTAB);
        const void *stringTbl = translateOffset(cache, symtab->stroff);
        uint32_t off = 0;
        while (off < symtab->strsize) {
                const char *e = &(stringTbl[off]);
                if (e[0] != 0)
                        printf("STR[%u]=\"%s\"\n", off, e);
                off += strlen(e) + 1;
        }
        return 0;
}
```